# which version of program will execute? the one in the /usr/bin or the one in /usr/local/bin?

Tags: python, unix, centos, version

I have python in both `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. Now I have this question that which one will execute if I call python?

I know that I can check with `which python` command to see which one is which one. But I'm asking which one would work by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at $PATH, typically `/usr/local/bin` comes first:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
$
```

and as the `$PATH` is search from left to right til a match is found, `/usr/local` wins.

You can of course test that by placing a script in either and have it echo its value...

Comment: Yes, that is the "specific" case of the OPs question, I answered in more generality why for example `type [-p] python` (and `which` is equivalent to `type -p`) works: it also searches the `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

When you run anything on the command-line, it will search through the folders in the `PATH` variable, **in order**, until it finds an executable file with that name.